# Why does this webworker cause these animations to lag?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, web-worker

I have set up a webworker to run an intensive calculation. On my main page, I have a spinning icon that is animated. However, when the webworker runs, my spinning icon lags. It seems to be browser dependent as well. I believe this is because despite using a separate js thread, the browser is still demanding too many resources from the computation, but I am not sure. Does anyone know why this happens? Or how I can fix it? Short of using a backend, I have no idea what to do.

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bohr-56u5k7?file=/src/App.js

`App.js`:

```
import { FaBeer } from "react-icons/fa"; // an icon

function App() {
  const myWorker = new Worker('Worker.js');

  myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('message received from worker', e.data);
  };

  function work() {
    myWorker.postMessage(3000000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <FaBeer className="spinner"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Worker.js`:

```
onmessage = function (e) {
  let n = 0;

  while (n < e.data) {
    n++;
  }

  postMessage("done");
};
```

`Styles.css`:

```
.spinner {
  animation: spin infinite 2s linear;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your while loop in the worker is not ending. what is the value of e.data within that function context?  e.data should be an array, not the value that you specified. so, you'd need to reference by e.data[0] , I think

Comment: My while loops ends (I receive a response after the loop closes)